# Aplicação Ruby que se mantém recarregando os arquivos fonte

Tags: ruby

Como posso projeter minha aplicação de modo que sempre que eu modifique e salve um arquivo .rb a aplicação passe a se comportar "do jeito novo"?

Eu estou fazendo uma aplicação que lê o comando, executa, imprime o resultado e lê o próximo comando (REPL, Read-Eval-Print-Loop). E gostaria que os fontes fossem recarregados sempre que eu os modificasse.

Mais ou menos da maneira que o Rails e o Unity(a engine gráfica) o fazem quando altero os scripts.

Alguém já fez algo parecido? Como posso fazer algo assim?

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar a gem [**rerun**](https://github.com/alexch/rerun). Instale com:

```
gem install rerun
```

E se seu programa se chama `script.rb`, execute com:

```
rerun script.rb
```

Ela monitorará o sistema de arquivos e reexecutará o comando sempre que algum arquivo for alterado. O único cuidado a levar em conta é que ele mata o processo anterior, então você pode acabar corrompendo algum arquivo de configuração (bons programas devem ser resistentes contra isso, é uma boa oportunidade para testar).

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria 2 coisas pra conseguir esse comportamento:

1. Incluiria um SignalHandler para capturar algum sinal do sistema operacional, como `USR1` (considerando que vc está em um *UNIX). E sempre que o processo receber esse sinal, fazer com que os fontes sejam recarregados.

```ruby
    Signal.trap("USR1") do
      load "caminho_pro_arquivo_que_deve_ser_recarregado.rb"
    end
```

1. Utilizaria o [watchr](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr) para monitorar as alterações no sistema de arquivos, de forma que sempre que algum dos fontes mude, ele envie o sinal `USR1` para o processo.